# Opencart Product Bands

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

Im still a newbie learning things day by day. I have posted my question at the OpenCart forum website looking for help and now here in StackOverflow. I need your help guys.

Hi there, Im a newbie getting used to Opencart environment. I need help with product bands as I have attached in picture below.
I need the coming_soon option to overwrite the out_of_stock option settings. Its not working correctly as Im confused with the logic that has been made. Out_of_stock option works when there is only "0" quantity products. When we have a new product that is Coming_soon we would make that product quantity "0" as well but something is wrong here and the Coming_soon is not overwriting the Out_of_stock setting. I need some help here.

[image: Coming_soon checkbox]

[image: Product quantity]

[image: Out of stock band]

[image: Coming Soon band]

**catalog/controller/product/category.php**

```
/*OOS Band start*/
            $optionsQty = 0;
            $oosQty = 0;
            foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($result['product_id']) as $option) {
                if ($option['type'] == 'select' || $option['type'] == 'radio' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $option['type'] == 'image') {
                    foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
                        $optionsQty++;
                        if ($option_value['quantity'] <=0) $oosQty++; 
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($optionsQty == $oosQty && $optionsQty > 0 ) {
            $band_oos = true;
            }
            else $band_oos = false;          /*OOS Band end*/
```

**catalog/view/product/category.tpl**

```
 <div class="for_infine">
                                <?php if ($product['band_oos']) { ?>
                                    <span class="band-oos">&nbsp;</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if ($product['band_free_shipping'] == 'Yes') { ?>
                                    <span class="band-free-shipping">&nbsp;</span>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php if ($product['band_new'] == 'Yes') { ?>
                                    <span class="band-new">&nbsp;</span>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php if ($product['band_coming_soon'] == 'Yes') { ?>
                                    <span class="band-coming-soon">&nbsp;</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <br />
```

**catalog/controller/product/product.php**

```
$this->data['options'] = array();

            $optionsQty = 0;
            $oosQty = 0;
            foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) { 
                if ($option['type'] == 'select' || $option['type'] == 'radio' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $option['type'] == 'image') { 
                    $option_value_data = array();

                    foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
                        $optionsQty++;
                        if ($option_value['quantity'] <=0) $oosQty++; 

                        if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
                            $price_original = $product_info['special'];
                        }else {
                            $price_original = $product_info['price'];

                        }
```

**catalog/view/product/product.tpl**

```
<div class="left">
            <div class="heading" style="line-height: 27px; font-size: 25px;"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
                <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
                <div class="image">


              <?php if ($band_oos ) { ?>
                <div class="oos_tab_large top-right-cnr"></div>
              <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($band_free_shipping == 'Yes') { ?>
                          <div class="free_shipping_tab_large top-right-cnr"></div>
                      <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($band_new == 'Yes') { ?>
                          <div class="new_tab_large top-right-cnr"></div>
                       <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($band_coming_soon == 'Yes') { ?>
              <div class="coming_soon_tab_large top-right-cnr"></div>
              <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please post your question here instead of linking to an off-site one.

Comment: sorry @jsheeran, I was even new to stackoverflow but now i manage to post it with the help of my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart out of stock warning can be disabled in settings:

Settings -> Your Store -> Edit -> Options -> Show Out Of Stock Warning

If you need both Stock Warning and Bands to work together you need to rethink new products adding with 0 quantity.

Comment: there are four bands over there. out of stock and coming soon is on top of one another. free shipping and new is on top of one another. when coming soon checkbox is ticked it should go on top of out of stock instead out of stock showing by default.

Comment: What extension you use for this bands?

Comment: There is no extension, it is hard coded following the default out_of_stock bands.

Comment: Add full catalog/view/product/product.tpl from start of div.left and will see what I can do